# How to convert List<dynamic> to List<OurClass> in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I create a dynamic list at run-time and after execution I need to assign the list to my class properties

```
List<tblchargemaster> charge = new List<tblchargemaster>();

charge = (List<tblchargemaster>) ObjDB.SelectQuery("tblchargemaster");
```

`tblchargemaster` is the class type and `SelectQuery` function returns `List<dynamic>`. How can I convert this dynamic list to a list with my class type?

```
     public List<dynamic> SelectQuert(string TableName)
    {
        Conn.Open();

        DataTable dt = new DataTable("map");

        string Query = "Select * from " + TableName;            
        MySqlDataAdapter dr = new MySqlDataAdapter(Query, Conn);
        dr.Fill(dt);

        List<dynamic> dynamicDt = dt.ToDynamic();

        Conn.Close();

        return dynamicDt;
    }
```

And Generic Class is

```
    public static class DataTableExtensions
{
    public static List<dynamic> ToDynamic(this DataTable dt)
    {
        var dynamicDt = new List<dynamic>();
        foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
        {
            dynamic dyn = new ExpandoObject();
            foreach (DataColumn column in dt.Columns)
            {
                var dic = (IDictionary<string, object>)dyn;
                dic[column.ColumnName] = row[column];
                dynamicDt.Add(dyn);
            }
        }
        return dynamicDt;
    }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a way to convert a dynamic or anonymous object to a strongly typed, declared object?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17101190/is-there-a-way-to-convert-a-dynamic-or-anonymous-object-to-a-strongly-typed-dec)

Comment: as mentioned in discussion to my answer this boils down to how to convert a dynamic to a `tblchargemaster`. Once you can do that for one object you can also do it for many objects.

Comment: i update my question friend please help me. . .

Comment: I posted a link to the Stackoverflow Q&A that answers your question. Did you read it?

Comment: Yes But that is js serialization how its help me

Comment: please help me friends

Comment: Type 'Sports.Models.tblchargemaster' is not supported for deserialization of an array. this error is come

Comment: You did not read my link carefully enough.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Edited, since explicit cast from dynamic to a strong type is not supported.

```
var charge = ObjDB.SelectQuert("tblchargemaster").Cast<tblchargemaster>();
```

becomes:

```
var charge = ObjDB.SelectQuert("tblchargemaster").Select(CastDynamicTo<tblchargemaster>)
```

whereas `CastDynamicTo<tblchargemaster>` is implemented by help of [Is there a way to convert a dynamic or anonymous object to a strongly typed, declared object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17101190/is-there-a-way-to-convert-a-dynamic-or-anonymous-object-to-a-strongly-typed-dec)

Comment: Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Sports.Models.tblchargemaster>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<Sports.Models.tblchargemaster>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Comment: Call ToList() method in the end

Comment: @Dinesh: looks like you did not copy my code 1:1. If you really want to explicitly type your `charge` as `List<..>` you will need to append a `.ToList()` after `.Cast<...>`

Comment: @Dinesh Can you rephrase that?

Comment: Again i getting error message as (Unable to cast object of type 'System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject' to type 'Sports.Models.tblchargemaster'.)

Comment: @Dinesh: That brings us down to the question of how to convert a dynamic to a strong type. I was presuming that a explicit cast would do the trick but it does not. However, this question has been answered already: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17101190/is-there-a-way-to-convert-a-dynamic-or-anonymous-object-to-a-strongly-typed-dec

Comment: Type 'Sports.Models.tblchargemaster' is not supported for deserialization of an array This error is come.

Answer (score 1):

Use `Cast<tblchargemaster>()` method:

```
List<tblchargemaster> charge = new List<tblchargemaster>();

charge = charge.AddRange(
   ObjDB.SelectQuert("tblchargemaster").Cast<tblchargemaster>());
```

Comment: Cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<Sports.Models.tblchargemaster> error like this